# To what extent if any did the Koch brothers facilitate an "attack on voting rights... that began after 2008"?

Tags: united-states, voting, campaign-finance, civil-rights, republican-primary

In CNN's November 30, 2023 [Will Koch’s endorsement be enough for Nikki Haley to beat Trump?](https://youtu.be/IR9uOPX2JYM?t=281), civil rights attorney [Maya Wiley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_Wiley) responds to a question about financial support linked to the [Koch brothers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_activities_of_the_Koch_brothers) contributing to the campaign of [Nicky Haley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikki_Haley) rather than the Republican primary front-runner Donald Trump. This is from the YouTube transcript with several "uh, you know"s removed and some punctuation inserted:

> CNN: How are Democrats Maya looking at this this morning; yes we recognize a state of where things are in terms of the power of Donal  Trump and where he sits this morning, but is Nikki Haley seen as a real threat?
>
> WILEY: I'm gonna go with Shane here. I think this is about the honorable mention in this campaign. I think it is interesting, and one thing that's particularly striking from   the standpoint of the statement that they made about the extremism that Donald Trump represents, and how Nikki Haley is the counter to that kind of flies in the face of their history of actually supporting getting Donald Trump not just elected, including some of the work that they helped to fund in Wisconsin in 2016, and the ads that helped support him by going after Hillary Hillary Clinton.
>
> But when you go back to the origins of why Donald Trump has been so dangerous for democracy his lies about the election in 2020, **this all goes back to the attack on voting rights that frankly was a signature of the Koch brothers that began after 2008, and the efforts to make it significantly more difficult for Americans lawfully allowed to vote, to vote.** And that's the origins of the great denial and the big lie. And that's something that we owe frankly to the Koch brothers **and to Alex.** Ao the roots of this very danger to democracy is essentially coming from the same folks that are now saying 'Oh wait, now democracy is in danger.'

**Question:** To what extent if any did the Koch brothers facilitate an "attack on voting rights... that began after 2008"?

Since Wiley is a strong advocate for voting rights and a lawyer not a journalist, this needs to be examined carefully, with facts and supporting sources.

"bonus points" for figuring out to whom "and to Alex" refers

Comment: I didn't find a [voting-rights] tag, so I've added [civil-rights] as the closest approximation I could think of.

Comment: *potentially* helpful to understand the difference between the Koch brothers *per se* and what I've asked about here; "financial support linked to the Koch brothers" might be found in [Five Myths About the Koch Brothers — And Why It Matters To Set Them Straight](https://billmoyers.com/story/five-myths-about-the-koch-network-and-why-it-matters-to-set-them-straight/)

Comment: Probably to the same extent that Elon Musk facilitated attacks on Jews. Some contributors don't like such Qs here that are not about 100% politicians, but interestingly this one isn't getting the usual flak, yet.

Comment: @Fizz I also don't like that individuals and entities with $$$zillions are such effective political operators and that politicians (and [the courts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_personhood#In_the_United_States)) facilitate and welcome that.

Comment: As far as I understand, *"attack on voting rights... that began after 2008"* is Democratic framing of the political issue that Republicans describe differently - something like *"preventing vote fraud"*. Without appropriate non-partisan discussion the question looks like promoting/discrediting a political issue.

Comment: The Kochs are widely demonized by the Dems.  And they did engage in a lot of funding of conservative causes.  Would be interesting to hear what the actual facts behind this claim are supposed to be.